# Getting Datatype mismatch in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, sybase, criteria

I have a table in Sybase database with a column is_req. Its datatype is char(1). Its property definition in my hbm file as:

property name="isRequired"  column="is_req" type="boolean"

Now, when I try to compare it using Criteria/Restrictions as:
`criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("isRequired", '1')`, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
at org.hibernate.type.BooleanType.set(BooleanType.java:37)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:62)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:44)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1115)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1177)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:390)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:218)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1593)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1577)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:111)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1322)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:300)
```

And if I try to do
`criteria.add("isRequired", Boolean.TRUE)`, I get following exception:

> com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'BIT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

```
at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:2796)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:2126)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:69)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:220)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:203)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java:1578)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:1563)
at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:85)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:120)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1272)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:391)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:218)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1593)
```

Is it possible to compare these values?

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to retrieve a char and cast it as a Boolean?

You can achieve this by using generic enum user types :
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType?_sscc=t

I have used this in the past to do so.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted to achieve, did it using Expressions as
criteria.add(Expression.sql("{alias}.is_req = '0'"))